# Set difference on RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to get a set difference on two rdd's i.e. a - b.

```
val a: RDD[A] = getARDD()
val b: RDD[A] = getBRDD()
```

where A is a class with a String field using lombok annotations

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A implements Serializable, Comparable<A> {
  String field;
}
```

Code that I have tried

```
val diff = a.keyBy(_.getField()).subtractByKey(b.keyBy(_.getField()).values
or
val diff = a.subtract(b)
or
val rdd1Grouped = a.groupBy(_.getField)
val rdd2Grouped = b.groupBy(_.getField)
val diff = rdd1Grouped.subtractByKey(rdd2Grouped).values
```

Both does not work. I thought grouping by key should work but it is not working. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

It gives the values in RDD1 i.e. val a

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work" - exception (post it)? Wrong results (show example)?

Comment: It gives whatever rdd was in val a. updated the question.

Comment: I changed subtract to use subtractByKey and it worked

`val diff = a.keyBy(_.getField()).subtractByKey(b.keyBy(_.getField()).values`